# trying to resolve a missing bootstrap object

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, selenium-webdriver

I am using Eclipse and Selenium on Windows 10.  My machine has a habit of crashing (at some point they are going to replace it).  It usually crashes when I am running a Selenium project.  (It probably has nothing to do with Selenium but that is what I am always running).  The laptop is connected to two monitors.  Occasionally I can lift the laptop screen and do a few things from the laptop, but not always.

The last time it crashed I was running something with the Chrome driver.  I was able to get onto the laptop for a short time, and exit Eclipse.  After I exited, the cursor remained a timer which meant it was trying to do something.  Shortly after that the machine stuck and I had to hit power.

When I powered it back on and connected to the VPN and brought up my Eclipse session, the workspace was there and the git library, but all the code had vanished from Eclipse (but it was still on the disk in the files).  Rather than foo with it I made a new workspace that had everything my previous workspace had.  However, when I tried to run an Eclipse program I got the following:

```
 java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.channelFactory(Lio/netty/channel/ChannelFactory;)Lio/netty/bootstrap/AbstractBootstrap;
 ...
 ...
 ChromeDriver.java:72
```

Often when this happens it is because the chromedriver version does not match Chrome version, but they did not change, and are both Version

```
 Chrome: 121.0.6167.161 (Official Build) (64-bit)
 ChromeDriver: 121.0.6167.85
```

these are the same up to the last digit (161 v. 85) I wouldn't think that makes a difference, but maybe it does?

This also happens with Edge.  Same error.

I did all the things you are supposed to do: maven clean each project, maven->update all projects with "Force Update of Snapshot/Releases" but same problem.  I tried stepping through the browser and Selenium code but is is very complicated.

I am running this with Eclipse -> Run as Java Application with the main class specified as our main class as always, and the project as the project it has always been.  In the VM arguments I specify the location to Chrome Driver.  Not sure whether I can share specifics due to company policy.

The interesting thing is, I also have some Testng projects and they still work, so I am not sure what is going on.  Maybe there is a maven -> deep clean? ;-)

I found some kind of similar issues from a search but they are all with different special packages that I am not trying to use.

Any idea what to try?

To summarize:

```
   Chrome: 121.0.6167.161 (Official Build) (64-bit)
   ChromeDriver: 121.0.6167.85   
   Java: Red Hat java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.332-2  (we switched about a week ago)
   Eclipse: 2018-12
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>4.11.0</version>
   </dependency>
```